# Oracle - Join two tables by concatenating repeating rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have 2 tables like this :

table_a

```
id  col2
1   A
1   B
2   A
2   B
3   B
```

table_b

```
id  col1
1    X
2    Y
3    Z
```

result:

```
id col1 col2
1   X    A_B
2   Y    A_B
3   Z    B
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `listagg()`:

```
select b.id, b.col1,
       listagg(a.col2, '_') within group (order by a.col2) as col2
from table_b b join
     table_a a
     on b.id = a.id
group by b.id, b.col1;
```